# What's the proper way to pass an array variable from one function to a subsequent function

Tags: php, function

Both of the two techniques below seem to work okay. I would just like to know which technique is the most proper technique.

```
// parameters
$text_str = 'antique picture';
$error_arr = array();
```

The `$error_arr` variable is included in the parameters:

```
function step_one($text_str,$error_arr) {
 global $error_arr;
 //... some code goes here ...
 $error_arr['step_one'] = true; 
}

function step_two($text_str,$error_arr) {  
  global $error_arr;
 //... some code goes here ...
 $error_arr['step_two'] = true; 
}

// call the two functions that have $error_arr included in the parameters
step_one($test_str,$error_arr);
step_two($text_str,$error_arr);

// they output the following
print_r outputs array('step_one' => 1)
print_r outputs array('step_one' => 1, 'step_two' => 1)
```

The `$error_arr` variable is omitted from the parameters.

```
function step_one($text_str) {  
 global $error_arr;
 //... some code goes here ...
 $error_arr['step_one'] = true; 
}

function step_two($text_str) {  
  global $error_arr;
 //... some code goes here ...
 $error_arr['step_two'] = true; 
}

// call the functions that have the $error_arr variable omitted from the parameters
step_one($text_str);
step_two($text_str);

// the last two functions have exactly the same output as the
// first two functions even though the `$error_arr` is not included 
// in the parameters

print_r outputs array('step_one' => 1)
print_r outputs array('step_one' => 1, 'step_two' => 1)
```

I am running PHP 7.1 on a shared hosting. I have got `display_errors` turned on in the control panel.

PHP does not throw any error messages if I include the `$error_arr` variable in the parameters or if I use the functions that omit the `$error_arr` variable from the parameters.

Comment: Both approaches are outright _wrong_! Do not use `global`! Never! You can hand over that array as a reference argument (`&$error_arr`) if you have to. But much better is to use exceptions.

Comment: PHP won't throw any errors because you named a variable as $error_arr. If you want PHP to throw hard errors, use the "Exception" class (http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php). Both of your examples are nasty, and I would avoid globals. Especially the first example (passing the same variable in as you declare as a variable, ouch).

Comment: @arkascha Thanks for the info. (&$error_arr) seems to be working. I tried that earlier today and got error messages. I commented out global in my functions and it's still working. :)

Comment: @Randall Thanks for the response.  I will check out the Exception class in the PHP Manual. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like:

```
$error_arr = [
  'step_one' => step_one($text_str),
  'step_two' => step_two($text_str),
];
```

It is not clear from the question what is the purpose of this code, so some approaches or other may be better. For example if you need to process `$text_str` in several steps just in this particular place - you can use closures instead:

```
$processing = [
  'step_one' => function($str) { /* some code */ return true },
  'step_two' => function($str) { /* some code */ return true },
];
$results = [];
foreach($processing as $func) {
  array_push($results, $func($text_str));
}
```

If you want these functions to share some variable - you can pass it through `use` clause:

```
$shared = [];
$processing = [
  'step_one' => function($str) use ($shared) { /* some code */ return true },
  'step_two' => function($str) use ($shared) { /* some code */ return true },
];
$results = [];
foreach($processing as $func) {
  array_push($results, $func($text_str));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The two techniques are actually the same technique.

Here's an example:

```
$error_arr = ['example' => 'value'];

$not_error_arr = ['something' => 'else'];

function step_one($text_str, $error_arr) {
    global $error_arr;
    $error_arr['step_one'] = true;
}

step_one('foo', $not_error_arr);

var_dump($error_arr, $not_error_arr);
```

This will output

> array (size=2)
>     'example' => string 'value' (length=5) 'step_one' => boolean true
>
> array (size=1)
>     'something' => string 'else' (length=4)

The 'step_one' value is *not assigned to the array you passed as a parameter*, because that assignment has been overriden by the `global $error_arr`.

So, regardless of what you pass as the second argument to

```
function step_one($text_str,$error_arr) {...
```

the global definition within the function means it will be ignored. It only looks like you're writing to it because the variable in global scope happens to be the same one you passed as a parameter.